# How can I make a USB cable use a push button & capacitor to allow power to flow?

Tags: usb

I'm looking for a way to make a usb cable have a push button connected to allow power to flow.

[image: rough schematic]

'Device_X' should have a momentary button and, I'm assuming, a capacitor that gets charged when the button is pushed.  Which allows the power to flow.

But I am at a loss if this is possible or even if it has been done somewhere else.

The ultimate goal is to create a power source for a raspberry pi that can later be turned off from the pi itself.  So push to start and the rest will sort itself out.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Ty.

Comment: this is what you call an XY question ... asking for help with what you consider to be a solution to a problem, instead of asking for help with the problem itself ... please update your post ... please do not make assumptions

Comment: @jsotola Why do you think this demonstrates a solution instead of conveying the idea needed?!?

Comment: You're looking for a soft power latch

Comment: What you want to do or think you can do with a button and a capacitor cannot be done with a button and a capacitor, so there is no answer how to do it. You need to loosen up the requirements to include other components as well.

Comment: @MiNiMe Ty, this looks like what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are going to 3D-print a "custom USB cable plug"/"Thingy where a cable goes in and comes out", which you can plug into e.g. a wall-adapter to then feed your raspberry can be done in multiple ways!

**(1) Power-Latch**

There a dedicated ICs that function as a latch to the positive supply rail. You could just put it into the 5V path and add the push-button as HMI.

**(2) Micro**

You could also over-engineer it and use a small microcontroller. This controller could use additional components to e.g. meassure voltage and current. It could be used as either a power-logger (plug it into your PC every now and then and "download" the data) or it could integrate WiFi/Bluetooth (Maybe automating a switch on/of policy is interesting to you?) or .... or .... ! You get the idea.

**(3) Just buy it**

This is **not a product recommendation** - just to give you and idea about how many problems and how much effort your can avoid by [investing](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Generic-Female-Adapter-Cable-Switch/dp/B01K41EWSA) *4.71€* or by [burning your capital](https://www.elektor.de/usb-a-to-usb-c-cable-with-on-off-switch) worth *4.95€*.

I would be amazed if you could get the components for either of solution **(1)** or **(2)** in a one-off for this price - not to talk about e.g. a PCB or your time.

**Of course**, if its about the "learning"/"challange": I respect that and encourage you to go on!